# Chatterbot Django Integration Retrieving Conversation Data

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

I am working on a chatterbot Django integration. What I need is to retrieve the conversation data entered through Django admin console. I define the chatterbot as follows

```
chatbot = ChatBot(
        "SQLMemoryTerminal",
        storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
)
```

Now I am trying to retrieve response as follows

```
response =  chatbot.get_response("usa money")
```

The response I expect via. admin is "Dollar". But instead of that, I get previously entered statement only. Can anybody help me to retrieve conversation data from the admin console? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your corpus data ? Also if you are expecting specific ouput for the given input why not try `specify adapter` or You can also write your custom adapter that can response to your query...!

Comment: Have you trained the model for usa monetary system? If yes, then, you may want to use specific or best match adapter. Also, make sure you have  data in the conversation's table in admin? Otherwise, you may end up getting the same response as your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you trained the model for USA monetary system? If yes, then, you may want to use specific or best match adapter. Also, make sure you have data in the conversation's table in admin. Otherwise, you may end up getting the same response as your statement.